# std::memcpy vs std::copy_n for legacy c structs

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

In dealing with legacy `C` code, I need to read and copy the memory location of a C-style struct.
Given a pointer to the struct, should I better use the C-style `std::memcpy` or the C++ `std::copy_n`? Or are they equivalent?

To have a concrete, albeit trivial, example:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

struct Ctype {
   double x;
   int a;
};

int main()
{
   Ctype a{1, 2};
   auto p = &a;
   auto buffer = reinterpret_cast<decltype(p)>(::operator new(sizeof(a)));


   // Are the two following equivalent and both well-defined?
   std::memcpy(buffer, p, sizeof(a));
   std::copy_n(p, 1, buffer);

   Ctype b{3, 4};
   // Are the two following equivalent and both well-defined?
   std::memcpy(&b, buffer, sizeof(b));
   std::copy_n(buffer, 1, &b);

   delete buffer;
   return 0;
}
```

The question arises in the context of serializing a C struct. In the concrete case I do not know the  contents of `Ctype` which is defined in a C library.

**Some clarifications**

The example is perhaps overly simplified, and clearly one could simply use `b=*buffer`.  What I have in mind, however, is that `buffer` could be provided from outside, for example it could be a sequence of data read from the disk. Then I need to actively copy buffer into b.

**Addition**

This is an example closer to what I have in mind. It uses the `zlib` library to write/read from the disk: the zlib functions `gzread` and `gzwrite` accept a `void *` pointer to a buffer of memory to read/write.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

extern "C" {
#include <zlib.h>
}

struct Ctype {
   double x;
   int a;
};

int main()
{
   Ctype a{1, 2};
   auto p = &a;
   auto buffer = ::operator new(sizeof(a));

   // Are the two following equivalent and both well-defined?
   std::memcpy(buffer, p, sizeof(a));
   std::copy_n(p, 1, static_cast<Ctype *>(buffer));

   // Saving the files
   gzFile f = gzopen("conf.dat", "w");
   gzwrite(f, buffer, sizeof(a));
   gzclose(f);

   Ctype b{3, 4};
   // Reading file
   f = gzopen("conf.dat", "r");
   gzread(f, buffer, sizeof(a));
   gzclose(f);
   // Are the two following equivalent and both well-defined?
   std::memcpy(&b, buffer, sizeof(b));
   std::copy_n(static_cast<Ctype *>(buffer), 1, &b);

   operator delete(buffer);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just `*buffer = b;`? Since it's a C-style struct, you don't have to worry about constructors or destructors.

Comment: What do you mean that you don't know the contents of `Ctype`? You mean it might not be double+int or that you don't know their values?

Comment: @Barmar I have in mind a situation where buffer is given from *outside* and you want to initialize b with buffer by explicitly copying the memory contents.

Comment: @ALX23z I don't know if it is int, double, or something else. All I know is that if I include the C library I have this type Ctype, and it is a C struct. I could, of course, inspect the C code, but that defies the idea of using the C library as "user".

Comment: @francesco If you can use `sizeof(b)` you must have access to the structure definition.

Comment: @francesco if at compile time compiler doesn't know what the `Ctype` is even is then you cannot instantiate it or measure its size. Only pass pointers and references.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I know I must have a definition, and it is in fact provided by the C library. As commented above, I would avoid to inspect the C library to see precisely how Ctype is defined. I want to use Ctype more like a "user" and include it into a c++ class.

Comment: Regarding the clarificaiton, it might help to show in code what you mean.  If you want to read from a disk into a char buffer, and then copy the char buffer into `b`, then you would use a char buffer, not the `buffer` in your code. Or you could read directly from the device into `b` with no middle man

Answer (score 2):

`std::copy_n` is a template function that performs copy operations. For trivially copyable types (C style structs should all be trivially copyable) it is the same as `memcpy` - and should have the same performance.

Also, `memcpy` is not suitable for non-copyable types unlike `std::copy_n`.

Answer (score 1):

The first code is incorrect as you attempt to copy into storage that contains no objects. memcpy and copy_n can only update existing objects, they cannot create objects in vacant storage . An easy fix would be to write write `auto buffer = new Ctype;`  (although I would suggest using a container for for memory management if you must use dynamic allocation).

Having fixed that, your two methods are both equivalent for a C-style struct (i.e. one whose definition is syntactically valid in C). These are a subset of *trivially-copyable* types in C++.  So it is a matter of style as to which to use; my preference would be to write:

```
b = *buffer;
```

which seems clearer than a function call syntax .  A problem with the memcpy version is that it would not be robust in the case of future code changing the struct to no longer be trivially copyable.